# Best XMPP client library for Node.js

Tags: node.js, xmpp

What are your experiences with Node.js XMPP client libraries? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would highly recommed [node-xmpp](https://github.com/astro/node-xmpp), which is the most idiomatic library available for Node, in that each connection is an EventEmitter which emits events in a similar manner to the built in modules.

If you are coming at Node from a browser-based background, the way stanzas are constructed is identical to [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/), which minimizes the learning curve.

As you venture further into XMPP territory, node-xmpp is also a great way to write components.  And its architecture is clean enough that there is even an [xmpp-server](https://github.com/superfeedr/xmpp-server) project being built on it.

Finally, I'm also developing [Junction](https://github.com/jaredhanson/junction), which is a suite of XMPP middleware, similar in style to what Connect/Express offers for HTTP.  I'm currently building out examples and additional documentation, but the source code has full API docs, and I think its a solid framework, particularly if you are incorporating various XEPs into your client/component.

Comment: Another option is https://conversejs.org - https://github.com/jcbrand/converse.js which is under much more active development than node-xmpp or Junction.

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to build a bot for Google Talk, I would suggest using https://github.com/simple-xmpp/node-simple-xmpp

Node-xmpp did not work for me while connecting with google's servers.